# How to convert fat arrow AngularJS to coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, lodash

I have code in AngularJS and converting to writing it to CoffeeScript file.

```
  let usedNames = _.map(existedEntries, entry => entry.name);
```

I would need help to convert fat arrow (=>) to CoffeeScript. While compiling the above code I'm getting the error message "Unnecessary fat arrow".

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haru53

hmmm.. To convert this code to coffeescript, just change the "fat arrow" to the "slim" one. :). That's what you want?

```
usedNames = _.map(existedEntries, (entry) ->
    entry.name
)
```

Comment: No problem Haru ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Mauricio Sipmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52826667/5157454).

You can avoid the callback function by using the [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) shorthand iteraty:

```
usedNames = _.map(existedEntries, 'name');
```